# Multiple lines of text : No change in text format

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a multiple lines of text column in list , specify the type of text to allow : Rich text but When text is displayed , Text formatting is not applied

Comment: What do you mean? Is the text formatting not visible when you display a single item, when you edit it or in the list view?

Comment: for example i bold text or italic , but when text is displayed , not bold

Comment: i edit question

Comment: What browser do you use? Do you have JavaScript disabled?

Comment: ie,firefox,chrome.. NO

Comment: Maybe you have a custom css style that overwrites the style of the text?

Comment: Do you get the rich edit box in edit mode? What browser are you using?

Comment: thanks , find my answer , i use ..disable-output-escaping="yes"

Comment: Is this specific to SharePoint? Looks like it should have stayed on SO

Comment: I agree this is probably off-topic, but may be relevant in the context of XSLT editing for a SharePoint web part for example, although the question doesn't say this. I have merged this with the one migrated - must have been cross-posted, so at least only the one question now. @niloo : see the the [FAQ](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) for general advice on the scope of questions we are able to answer here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```